# App_WorkbookOpen not responding when opening XLS workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, xls

I'm writing a simple macro to solve a common problem for people who use XLS with multiple monitors.  Often, a workbook is saved in the second window and will not appear in the main window when re-opened.

To get around this, I have attempted to use the App_WorkbookOpen function and have encountered several problems.

1. This code only runs when opening a fresh instance of XLS.
2. This code opens the workbook, but does not display it in the windows menu.
3. This code interacts only with the personal.xls template.

I've included several lines of code to test what the macro is interacting with.
The code resides in ThisWorkbook section of my personal template.

The core code works if placed in an individual worbook, but I'd like it to run in all Wb_open situations.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
On Error Resume Next 'error handling, remove when final
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If ActiveWindow.Left > Application.UsableWidth Then
        ActiveWindow.Left = 15
        ActiveWindow.Top = 10
    End If

    MsgBox "New Workbook:" & Wb.Name 'what wkbook?, remove when final


If Error Then End
End Sub
```

Any thoughts?